# Material-UI Datepicker can't display error/required messages

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to show a validation error message on Date picker like how we do for TextField using errorText and errorStyle props but the validation error message is not working for DatePicker.

I am using material-ui version "^0.18.7".

Please find full functionality below. I am not sure exactly how to implement this. I also understand that the errorText and errorStyle is not a valid prop to DatePicker. Thought it will work for datepicker but it is not. Is there a way to achieve this.

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

constructor(props){
   super(props)
   const dateYesterday = new Date();
   dateYesterday.setDate(dateYesterday.getDate() - 1);
   this.state={
      dob: null,
      dobError: '',
      dateYesterday: dateYesterday
   }
   this.changeDateOfBirth = this.changeDateOfBirth.bind(this)
}

changeDateOfBirth = (evt, date) => {
if(date == null || date == undefined){
  this.setState({
    dobError: 'Please select your date of birth'
  });
}else{
  this.setState({
    dobError: '',
    dob: date
  });
}
}
const errorStyle = {
    display: 'table'
}

<DatePicker 
    dialogContainerStyle={{position: 'absolute'}} 
    errorText={this.state.dobError} 
    errorStyle={errorStyle} 
    inputStyle={myTheme.inputStyleText} 
    underlineStyle={myTheme.underlineStyle} 
    underlineFocusStyle={myTheme.underlineStyle} 
    floatingLabelStyle={myTheme.floatingLabelStyle} 
    floatingLabelText="Date Of Birth" 
    hintText="Select Date Of Birth" 
    container="inline" 
    locale="en-US" 
    firstDayOfWeek={0} 
    autoOk={true} 
    value={this.state.dob} 
    onChange={this.changeDateOfBirth} 
    defaultDate={this.state.dateYesterday}
 >
 </DatePicker>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: If you can update to v1, the `error` prop is available on the date picker.

Comment: Nope I can’t update to v1. My project is very large. If you look at v1 everything got changed and it’s completely new. If I have to update to v1 then I have to change everything it’s like from scratch again. Is there a way to fix this without upgrading to v1?

Comment: I am able to achieve displaying error message with Snackbar bar but I want to display it like normal error message below the datepicker underline. Since I am already using snackbars for displaying server responses so I can’t use the same for validation messages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DatePicker` spreads props through to children elements, so you can in fact use the `errorText` and `errorStyle` props from the `TextField` element. For example, I tested the following `DatePicker` in "^0.18.7" and can confirm it shows up with a red error message:

```
<DatePicker hintText="Portrait Dialog" errorText="This is an error message." />
```

You should be aware that the `onChange` callback in the `DatePicker` is only fired when a date is selected, so the `date` argument will never be null or undefined. In other words, you'll never enter into the following `if` statement:

```
if(date == null || date == undefined){
  this.setState({
    dobError: 'Please select your date of birth'
  });
}
```

If you want to check for cases in which the user has not set any kind of date, consider just checking whether or not your DOB is null (I left out the irrelevant props to keep things short):

```
<DatePicker 
    errorText={this.state.dob ? {} : this.state.dobError} 
    errorStyle={this.state.dob ? {} : errorStyle} 
 >
```

Comment: Thanks Jules. I will check and confirm this.

Comment: Jules I haven’t tested yet because my laptop is not with me now. I will test it on this Friday and update here without fail.

Comment: Jules your answer works fine and the code that I posted in my question works fine too. I had non manadatory field before Datepicker so it was not showing an error message. Only after filling non mandatory field it shows date picker error message when I click on submit again. Thanks for your time.