# Issue with MUI 5 datePikker when we add inputFormat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

what happens if I select a date by clicking on the calendar it works fine but if I set inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" then I will type the date it will not react like date format its go like **11111111111111111111** it is considered as a string like this so its break the format of date but if I select from the calendar it works fine but only if I will edit direct type it goes wrong.

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `mask` props to your code.

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  mask="____/__/__"
/>
```

Comment: any idea about helper text outside in this render TextField means I don't need to add helper text directly in this <TextField {...params} /> is using this date picker in the common component so I need to pass in prod but I trying but is not work

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358999/material-ui-datepicker-cant-display-error-required-messages

Comment: nope this is not what I need for helper text

Comment: I am using MUI version  5

Comment: I guess you need to use FormControl. then you can use helpertext outside the textfield. I am still learning so dont know much. https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#useformcontrol